# Adding New Lines to Strings Based on Character Count

Tags: java, string

So I'm trying to put a limit on a line of text and tell it when to start a new line. 
So if the entered text is *greater* than 12, a new line will be made and it will continue.

So far I've got the beginning of the if statement and then I'm lost. I've looked through the methods branching from the string named inputName but couldn't find what I'm searching for.

```
if (inputName.length() > 12) {
    inputName.
}
```

Comment: So do you want to split up your String into individual Strings of length <= 12, or would you like to add newline characters into the original String, so that printing the String will then not contain any lines longer than 12 ?

Comment: the second option, where after 12 characters itll start a new line and continue the original string

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this. Keep cutting off the string until it falls below 12.

```
while (inputName.length() > 12) {
    System.out.println(inputName.substring(0,12));
    inputName = inputName.substring(12);
}
System.out.println(inputName);
```

Comment: That seems to be tossing errors, saying substring only accepts `substring(int, int)` or `substing(int)`

Comment: try it again, I fixed it

Comment: Hm.. that seems to be just deleting the first 12 characters for some reason, (P.S: You forgot the ( ) after `length` in the while loop.)

Comment: No, this is correct. Of course it does modify inputName, which may not be what you want. In that case you could use a dummy variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
 String inputName="1234567890121234567890121234567890121234567890121234567890";
 while (inputName.length() > 12) {
        System.out.print(inputName.substring(0,12)+System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        inputName = inputName.substring(12);
 }
 System.out.print(inputName+System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can do to get you started :

```
    String inputname = "This is just a sample string to be used for testing";

    for (int i = 12; i < inputname.length(); i+= 13) {
        inputname = inputname.substring(0, i) + "\n" + inputname.substring(i, inputname.length());
    }
    System.out.println(inputname);
```

OUPUT :

```
This is just
 a sample st
ring to be u
sed for test
ing
```

Comment: Your code produces output where the first line break is after the 12th character, but all subsequent line breaks are after the 11th character.

Comment: oh sorry, my bad... I've updated it already. Thanks for checking

Answer (score 0):

You should divide `inputName.length()` by 12 to get the number of new lines needed. Then add the new lines using a for loop and `String#substring()`. Making sure to offset the substring by 1, since `"\n"` was added.

For instance:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int MAX_LENGTH = 12;
    String foo = "foo foo foo-foo foo foo-foo foo foo-foo.";

    // only care about whole numbers
    int newLineCount = foo.length() / MAX_LENGTH;

    for (int i = 1; i <= newLineCount; i++) {
        // insert newline (\n) after 12th index
        foo = foo.substring(0, (i * MAX_LENGTH + (i - 1))) + "\n"
                + foo.substring(i * MAX_LENGTH + (i - 1));
    }

    System.out.println(foo);
}
```

Output:

```
foo foo foo-
foo foo foo-
foo foo foo-
foo.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the string in memory, then you could do

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int begin = 0, end = begin + 12; begin < src.length()
        && end < src.length(); begin += 12, end = begin + 12) {
    sb.append(src.substring(begin, end));
    sb.append('\n');
}
System.out.println(sb);
```

It iterates through the string and appends a new line for every 12 characters.